# Python's telling me there's a syntax error, please explain

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, pi

### Invalid Syntax: *What has gone wrong?*

Basically, I tried to make a Pi calculator using a variety of different methods I've found myself. This is my most recent idea (probably already exists but checking if it does ruins the fun imo).

```
def pi_calculator(x):
    n = 1.0
    y = 0.0
    while n < x:
        y += 4 * ((-1)**(n - 1) / ((2 * n) + 1)
        n += 1
    return y

print pi_calculator(1000)
```

Specifically, it's telling me there's a syntax error with `n += 1`

```
    n += 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm quite new to Python and have no idea what's going on here, **it's saying the same thing on multiple shells or IDEs (whatever they're called)**; so I'd appreciate any feedback.
In advance, I'd like to also say that I have no idea if this program would work - as it stands - so don't pick me up on that please, I'll like to figure it out myself :P

**(Using Spyder; Python 2.7)**

Comment: You're missing an enclosing `)` on the above line, starting with `y += ...`

Comment: While I think the error is easy to spot I wish that Python would be a bit more specific. Just parsing the last line it could have hinted that maybe a missing ) is causing the error. Just as an example: Matlab does it. ;) At least IDEs often help there too.

Comment: And after that, it doesn't work, cherry on the cake haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be

```
y += 4 * ((-1)**(n - 1) / ((2 * n) + 1))
```

The last `)` is missed in **line 5**: which is

```
y += 4 * ((-1)**(n - 1) / ((2 * n) + 1)
```

Comment: Oh wow, How could I not notice this? xD I just assumed the worst straight away.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expensive way to switch signs:

```
(-1)**(n - 1)
```

+1 for n=1, -1 for n=2, +1 for n=3, etc.

I'd use an if test and spare myself the exponentiation.

Comment: Any ideas on the most efficient way to do this? or is `if n % 1 = 0: ... else:...` decent enough?

Comment: And I originally wrote this on paper as the sum of all numbers from n=1 to infinity: then basically used that formula, so it was just a test to see if it worked, first

Comment: yes, that's what i'd do.